# Find the component(connectness) of this.

Tags: general-topology

Let the usual topology $U$ over $\mathbb R$

Say $(\mathbb R^2, T) = (\mathbb R, U) \times (\mathbb R, U)$

$Y = \mathbb R^2 -A^2$ for irrational number set, $A$.

Find the component of the $O(0,0)$ in $(Y,T_y)$

(Here the $T_y$ is a relative topology)

---

Someone who gave me this question said The answer is $Y$.

My thought)

But I don't know why does it the component. 
Should be answer $ Y $is unconnected and also component is $(0,0)$ itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it should not: $Y$ is in fact path-connected. Let $(x,y)\in Y$. This means that either $x\in\Bbb Q$ or $y\in\Bbb Q$. In the first instance, the function $$f(t)=\begin{cases}(2tx,0)&\text{if }0\le t\le\frac12\\ (x,(2t-1)y)&\text{if }\frac12<t\le 1\end{cases}$$

is an arc in $Y$ from $0$ to $(x,y)$. In the second instance, the function $$g(t)=\begin{cases}(0,2ty)&\text{if }0\le t\le\frac12\\ ((2t-1)x,y)&\text{if }\frac12<t\le 1\end{cases}$$ is.